# How to beat 5 supports in League of Legends Blind pick

Tags: league-of-legends

I recently played against Taric, Sona, Janna, Soraka, and Lulu in a blind pick. They all had Heal.

We got destroyed. We were: Warwick, Fiora, Swain, Nautilus, and Caitlyn.

I jungled Warwick. Fiora went top (probably the reason we lost), Swain mid, and Nautilus and Caitlyn bot.

It was nuts. They had destroyed 6 towers and gotten Baron by level 14.

What would have been the best strategy for beating this team?

Comment: Ignite, and a team that actually understands the game. You shouldn't lose to a team with 5 supports, they have no damage.

Comment: They were damaging hard. Jana is a sick AP and Lulu hits like a truck early game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Packing Ignite would have lowered their healing on a champion at a time so you could focus them, and Executioner's Calling would have done the same. Because of all their Magic and hard CC, you all should have had Merc Treads and MR. Other than that, just focus the squishier people that can do damage when the fights start. Probably should have gone Lulu > Sona > Janna > Soraka > Taric.

Comment: The problem was the Blind Pick mode - we could not have all gotten ignite. What does executioners calling do?

Comment: I definitely should have gotten an executioners calling: Passive  Unique: On-hit, you cause 4 damage per second for 8 seconds.
Active  Unique: Inflicts target enemy champion with Grievous Wound, causing 50% reduced healing and regeneration for 8 seconds (20 second cooldown).

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar experience, but instead of 5 supports it was 5 tanks with smite. They shut me down since I was jungler, but they left top alone (Nasus) which is why I think they lost. On topic though If all supports went their offensive build as Lulu AP, Janna AP, Taric AS, Soraka AP, and Sona AD that might be a little harder. Usually for blind pick and even ranked I try choosing the offensive summoner spell that no one has. Such as 4 exhausts I would take ignite. That would fix the ignite problem and MR to counter the AP supports. I can see how this would hard since you've never seen this composition before. The first would be to focus the squishiest or the strongest. It also seems like your team might not have been so bright. I've personally haven't seen this composition either, but i think the previous comment also gives some good insight.

Answer (score 0):

Summoner spells isn't really going to swing the battle.  The easiest way is to realize the weaknesses in their team comp and play accordingly.  In this case, they lack a real ranged AD.  Ranged AD carries start taking over the game in the late game, so you really have to wait it out to the late game and hope your ranged AD can turn the balance.  Play defensively.  AP Janna won't lose to anyone mid, but at same time can't beat them outright, especially with a defensive summoner as heal.  Just let the lanes play out as a farm war, and your champs scale better than theirs which is the reason they are Support champs and not carries.  Support champs provide utility without items, while carries do lots of damage with items.

Answer (score -1):

I played with some friends ( all about summoner lvl 15-25) I am the only one that smurfed, to get fairer opponents ( I played support for the fairness ;-) ) We hit a team with janna wukong top sona mid and soraka, lulu bot.. and i never got harassed and even destroyed so hard in a botlane.. Soraka kept on spamming her moonfire and lulu threw her whatevers on us so that i had to port back on lvl 1 cuz i didnt thought they would deal that much damage. When i was in our base my carry got killed.. after 15 minutes of that i left the game cuz i was so pissed that their trollgame worked out :/ i think the point is that you undersestimate the damage of a support champ that gets ap items and the moment you realize it its too late.. These guys played so hardcore aggressive and if you think you can kill one, they healed up so much of their health through summonerspells / healspells..

Answer (score -2):

Tons of damage, heavy poke, 5 ignites, NO BRUISERS, 2-3 bursters, 1 sustain poker and 1 badass tank.